# HighCharts angular not working with dynamic data from Angular service

Tags: angular, highcharts

Trying to assign dynamic values coming from angular service in angular component does not update HighChart. If I call drawChart from outside of service response subscribe method, it works but with hardcoded data because response data is not available outside subscribe method.

1. Following are HighChart options.

   ````
       chart:{ type: "bar"},
       title: {text:null},
       xAxis:{categories:null},
       yAxis: {
         title:{
           text:"time (seconds)"
         }
       },
       tooltip: {
         valueSuffix:"seconds"
       },
       series: []
        };```
   ````
2. HighChart on my HTML.

   ````
       [Highcharts] = "SomeChart"
       [options] = "ChartOptions"
       style = "width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
      </highcharts-chart>```
   ````
3. This high chart is being populated by following code in angular component.

   ````
       let resp = this.RptService.getWorkflowAvgTime();
       resp.subscribe(reportData=> {this.DataSource.data = reportData as sommeObject[];
       this.drawChart(reportData);})
     }```
   ````
4. following is drawChart function

   ````
       {
           let s: Array<any> = []
           data.forEach(function (obj)
       {
            s.push({name: obj.yIdentifier, data:[obj.value]})
       })

          this.ChartOptions.series= s;
          console.log(this.ChartOptions.series); // Console prints proper values assigned to chartOptions 
       }```
   ````

Answer (score 2):

It is not working because to perform an update using the `highcharts-angular` you need to mark it by toggling the `updateFlag`. Without that, you will mutate the `chartOptions` but your chart will not update itself.

**Docs references:** 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details

**Live demo:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-c9zk9y?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```html
<highcharts-chart 
   [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
   [options]="chartOptions"
   [(update)]="updateFlag"
>
</highcharts-chart>

<button (click)="handleUpdate()">Update chart</button>
```

```js
export class AppComponent  {
   Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  updateFlag = false;

  data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  chartOptions: Options = {
    series: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        data: this.data
      }
    ]
  }


  handleUpdate() {
    this.chartOptions.title =  {
      text: 'updated'
    };

    this.chartOptions.series[0] = {
      type: 'line',
      data: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    }

    this.updateFlag = true;
  }
}
```